# In my table I need to be able to fill all the blank spaces in a column with text SSRS

Tags: excel, text, reporting-services, expression

In my SSRS table I have a column called *Ticket Due* and some of the text boxes below are empty as they have not been specified. What I need to do is set a expression that would take every blank space in that column and change it to *Unspecified*.

I am relatively new to SSRS so I don't exactly know what expression to write and the internet doesn't seem to have much help on how a newbie should counter this. (P.S: this is going to be exported to Excel later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do it after countless attempts for the past hour. It was `=IIF(Fields!TicketDue.Value,"","Unspecified")`.

To do this properly I had to make two expressions in one text box otherwise I would get errors. `=IIF(Fields!TicketDue.Value = nothing,"Unspecified","")` and `=IIF(Fields!TicketDue.Value = nothing,"",Fields!TicketDue.Value)`.